# How to train "doing multiple things at a time" (coordination)

Tags: exercise

I am generally good in using my body, for example when bouldering,
but i am terrible at dancing or any other activity where you have to do multiple things at a time, like driving a car.

How could i train this skill?

It would be good if i could train by doing these activities, but driving a car with my abilities is just too dangerous (especially for others).
As for dancing, that i just don't manage to do alone, and even beginners courses are way to difficult for me. I also don't have the money for private dance lessons.

Comment: What are you actually asking? How to become a dancer without practicing dancing?

Comment: i am asking for how to train this (i agree, quite abstract) skill of doing multiple things at once (cooking and talking is an other example). if i can do that to some extend, i could start learning to dance.

Comment: I agree that it is abstract. In fact, if you wish to learn to do something, you need to learn it from a teacher of that particular activity. He/she will be able to teach you how to combine it with other activities. Simply learning how to multitask isn't something any one person can teach you.

Comment: i don't want a single person to teach me how to multi-task. i am sure that learning one or more multitasking activities well will help you learn others more easily. some activities are well suited for this, others less. ahh.. this reminds me... i heard juggling is good for it. but you are probably right.. best to ask a dance teacher.